# Algorithm to identify similarity between text messages

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, text, similarity

I'm looking for an algorithm than can compare two text messages (let's say forum posts) and identify the similarity in percentage.

What would be the most efficient solution for this purpose?

The idea is to use this algorithm to identify users on a forum who have more than two nicknames, pretending to be different people.

I'm going to build a program that will read all their posts and compare each post from the first account to posts of the second account to find whether they are genuinely two different persons or just two registrations of a single user.

Comment: I think there are some good string comparison algorithm's out there.  I personally have used [this one before](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/default.aspx)  It has a very simple API and does a good job fairly quickly.

Comment: It depends a lot on what you mean by "similar" and "best." There are fast methods that do an okay job, there are slow methods that do a really good job, and lots of space in between. You might be interested in [Semantic similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_similarity), or you might be interested in [Stylometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylometry), which is determining if a particular bit of text is likely to have been written by a particular person. As asked, your question is way to broad to elicit a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came to my mind was the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but it is more focused on *words* similarities.

You could use [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf), but it will probably work better if your corpus contains more than only two documents.

An alternative could be representing the documents (posts) using a vector space model, like:

```
(w_0, w_1, ..., w_k)
```

where

- `k` is the total of terms (words) in your document
- `w_i` is the `i-th` term.

and then compute the [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), which basically compares two vectors (arrays) and count the positions where they are different. You can discard stop-words first (i.e. words like prepositions, etc.)

Take in count that the user might change some words, use synonyms, etc. There are lots of models for representing documents, computing similarity between them. Some of them take in count words dependency, which gives more semantic to the process, and others don't.

Comment: Hamming distance cannot be used here, because it compares vectors cell-by-cell. If one of the documents is shifted only by a single word, Hamming distance will be high.

Comment: @Warlord You're correct. Perhaps, in this case when comparing only two documents, a `diff` algorithm (like the used by `vimdiff`, Beyond Compare, etc) would fit better.

Answer (score 1):

[google-diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/downloads/list) will be a good choice for you. you can look the demo for testing.